# Allow Apps won't unlock in Security & Privacy - Yosemite

Tags: security, macos, preferences

When I was running Mountain Lion I selected "Allow apps downloaded from: Anywhere" in Security & Privacy. I updated to Yosemite a few days ago. The update set that back to: "Mac App Store and identified developers". I want to run some software from elsewhere. When I select Security & Privacy and click the padlock icon, a pane comes up asking me to enter my password. Since I don't have a password I simply click "Unlock". The padlock unlocks for a few milliseconds and re-locks far too quickly for me to change the setting. I know that I don't need a password as that pane lets me click Authenticate during software installation from a .dmg

So what do I have to do to change Allow apps setting now?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a few options:

- Temporarily set a password to change the setting.

or

- Hold down Ctrl, click on the app, then click Open from the menu shown. This will allow you to temporarily bypass the checks.

Comment: Thanks Stan, but that looks like a workaround for a "feature". Hopefully something will eventually be done to correct this. Cheers Chris

Answer (score 2):

You will need to temporarily put a password on, then you can just take it off. I had to do that for [Steam](http://store.steampowered.com) and it worked perfectly. I think this might be a bug and hopefully they're gonna fix it.

Comment: I am having the same issue. I tried the temp password and it did the trick. Truly it was annoying and I would be shocked if Apple doesn't fix this soon.

Comment: I was running into the exact same problem today. I'd try to open an app, and it'd pop up the not trusted dialog.

Opening the Security & Privacy settings then clicking "Open Anyway" did nothing.

If I changed the setting to "Anywhere" it just reverted back to the original setting.

I was unable to fix this using the GUI...

I *was* able to fix it using a command line tool.

Close your System Preferences, and open Terminal.app.

To see the status of Gatekeeper, run `spctl --status`.
To disable Gatekeeper, run `sudo spctl --master-disable`.
To enable Gatekeeper, run `sudo spctl --master-enable`.